# Convert emoji in a sentence to a word or text

Tags: python-3.x, emoji

I have sentences like : "This Place is awesome \xF0\x9F\x98\x89". I would like to replace the \xF0\x9F\x98\x89 with its corresponding text.
hence the result be like "This palce is awesome , winking smile.".
i am using python 3. i presume I can use the package emoji to demojize, but this takes the emoji rather then "\xF0\x9F\x98\x89".

```
mystr = "OMG the place is Awesome !!!!!!!!!!!! \xf0\x9f\x98\x9dl"
mystr = mystr.decode('utf-8')
print(emoji.demojize(mystr))
```

For this i get error :
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 1):

ByteStrings start with a `b` notation.

```
>>> mystr = "OMG the place is Awesome !!!!!!!!!!!! \xf0\x9f\x98\x9dl"
>>> mystr = mystr.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
>>> mystr = b"OMG the place is Awesome !!!!!!!!!!!! \xf0\x9f\x98\x9dl"
>>> mystr = mystr.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot.. yes my text was a bytestring.. i had just missed putting b'.... thanks a lot for pointing

Comment: Glad to be of help, you might wanna read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: the issue i am currently facing is.. i am trying to read a csv which has strings like : b"OMG the place is Awesome !!!!!!!!!!!! \xf0\x9f\x98\x9dl" but when csv is read thr panda.. its interpreting this as string.. so unable to use a .decode()